# Beautifulsoup returns empty for all table tags

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to access the table details to ultimately put into a `dataframe` and save as a `csv` with a limited number of rows(the dataset is massive) from the following site: https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2001-to-present/ijzp-q8t2/data

I'm just starting out webscraping and was practicing on this dataset. I can effectively pull tags like `div` but when I try `soup.findAll('tr')` or `td`, it returns an empty set.

The table appears to be embedded in a different code(see link above) so that's maybe my issue, but still unsure how to access the detail rows and headers, etc..., Selenium maybe?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [mcve], [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum.  Generally you should include example *input* and desired result along with the code that is faulty, describe why it is deficient and explain anything you have ruled out as the problem from your efforts to fix it. If *we* are able to copy and paste from your question with minimal effort to test your *stuff* you'll get more responses.

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of it, the website already allows you to export the data:

[image: Download]

As it would seem, the original link is:

```
https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2001-to-present/ijzp-q8t2/data
```

The `.csv` download link is:

```
https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/ijzp-q8t2/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD
```

The `.json` link is:

```
https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/ijzp-q8t2.json
```

Therefore you could simply extract the ID of the data, in this case `ijzp-q8t2`, and replace it on the download links above. [Here](https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.cityofchicago.org/ijzp-q8t2#pandas-py) is the official documentation of their API.

```
import pandas as pd
from sodapy import Socrata

# Unauthenticated client only works with public data sets. Note 'None'
# in place of application token, and no username or password:
client = Socrata("data.cityofchicago.org", None)

# Example authenticated client (needed for non-public datasets):
# client = Socrata(data.cityofchicago.org,
#                  MyAppToken,
#                  userame="user@example.com",
#                  password="AFakePassword")

# First 2000 results, returned as JSON from API / converted to Python list of
# dictionaries by sodapy.
results = client.get("ijzp-q8t2", limit=2000)

# Convert to pandas DataFrame
results_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, had some trouble with it so I tried using BeautifulSoup.  The CSV download was too large to work with.   Here's my latest attempt, curious if I'm the right track and how to transform my output into a cleaner dataframe.

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/ijzp-q8t2.json"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup)

output:
<html><body><p>[{"id":"11759644","case_number":"JC351057","date":"2019-07-13T23:55:00.000","block":"0000X E OHIO ST"}

Comment: Wouldn't recommend using `BeauitfulSoup` for this matter as it is used to extract information from websites, not document files (notice the `.json` extension). Instead, you should use something like `urlib`, `requests`, or `aiohttp` for the request portion of your application, and something like `json` or `pandas` to read in the data. Hopefully, you are using Jupyter Notebook, but if not, do yourself the favor and get it -- will make data analysis much easier. You can then do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/synchronizing/8ceb9f0bfe3643a03d8cd81c0b58e5b5).

Comment: I highly recommend getting experience with `pandas` -- this is one of the main libraries used for data analysis/manipulation with Python. Then for plotting, look into `matplotlib`, which should be more than enough for most use cases. However, before any of this, make sure to get Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Thanks very much Felipe.  Such a simple solution. I definitely over thought it.  I also appreciated the additional education.  Dumb question probably but the json link can applied as a csv link as well or was listed on the site somewhere and I missed it?  Thanks again!

Comment: To be honest, I simply changed the extension `.json` to `.csv` on the URL to see what would happen, and it seems to still work. If you were to try to a load a `.json` file using some sort of `csv` reader, it would most definitely not work (and vice-versa).